# Share a Function Across Multiple Cloud Code Files

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, commonjs

I want to have a `utilities.js` file that I require in my Parse Cloud Code that contains various functions that I share across my Cloud Code files.

So in `utilities.js` I would have:

```
function sheBear(){
  return "rawr rawr rawr"
}
```

...and in `whatever.js` I could have:

```
require('cloud/helpers/utilities.js')

Parse.Cloud.define("tester", function(request) {
  var she = sheBear()
  response.success(she)
})
```

...and get the return value of `sheBear()`. I can't get this to work (I get an error that `sheBear()` isn't defined). Is function sharing possible like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `sheBear()` function exposed from `utilities.js`, you'll need to alter it a little so it's exported as a module.

```
exports.sheBear = function() {
  return "rawr rawr rawr";
}
```

And then you can include in `whatever.js` as below:

```
var utilities = require('cloud/utilities.js');
var she = utilities.sheBear();
```

Source: Parse Documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-modules